# Derivation problem of second dispersion constant

Tags: dispersion

According to "Nonlinear fiber optics" from Agrawal the mode propagation constant $\beta = n\cdot\frac{\omega}{c}$ can be taylored into 
$$\beta = \beta_0+\beta_1(\omega-\omega_0)+\frac{1}{2}\beta_2(\omega-\omega_0)^2+\ldots$$
with
$$\beta_n = \left.\frac{d^n\beta}{d\omega^n}\right\vert_{\omega=\omega_0}$$
He also gives two examples for the first two derivations:
$$\beta_1 = \frac{1}{c}\left(n+\omega\frac{dn}{d\omega}\right)$$
$$\beta_2 = \frac{1}{c}\left(2\frac{dn}{d\omega}+\omega\frac{d^2n}{d\omega^2}\right)\\$$

Now I wanted to do the calculations myself, and started:
$$\begin{align}
\beta_2&=\frac{d\beta_1}{d\omega}\\
\frac{d\beta_1}{d\omega} &= \frac{d}{d\omega}\left(\frac{\omega}{c}\frac{dn}{d\omega}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{c}\left(\frac{dn}{d\omega}+\omega\frac{dn^2}{d\omega^2}\right)\\
&\neq\frac{1}{c}\left(2\frac{dn}{d\omega}+\omega\frac{d^2n}{d\omega^2}\right)
\end{align}$$
which is not the same as above. Where is my error? And how can I calculate it correctly?
Possible Error: I can not remove the $n$ from $\beta_1$, but rather have to include it as $\frac{dn}{d\omega}$ in my equation (resulting in $2\frac{dn}{d\omega}$ instead of $\frac{dn}{d\omega}$)?

Comment: You missed a term.  The index of refraction depends upon $\omega$.

Comment: @honeste_vivere: Question updated, I think I got it, thanks!

Comment: The first term in your $d \beta_{1}/d \omega$ equation should actually be two terms.  It should be:  $$\frac{d}{d \omega} \left( n + \omega \frac{d n}{d \omega} \right)$$